# Why does player 1 always get to take the first turn?

Tags: javascript

The page have 2 buttons named "Player  1" and "Player 2". User can click buttons to add number values to the header. The player with the highest number value win.

However, If a user try to click button called "player 2" first, nothing happen. How do I get button player 2 to take turn first if clicked?

```js
let p1Button = document.querySelector("#p1");
let p2Button = document.getElementById("p2");
let resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");
let numInput = document.querySelector("input");
let p = document.querySelector("p");
let winningscoreDisplay = document.querySelector("p span"); //slect p inside span
let p1Score = 0; //keep track of score
let p2Score = 0;
let p1Display = document.querySelector("#p1Display");
let p2Display = document.querySelector("#p2Display");
let gameOver = false; //keep track of state 
let winningscore = 5;
let turnTacker = 0; //keep track of p1Score and p1Score turn

p1Button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (!gameOver) {
    if (turnTacker == 0) {
      turnTacker = 1;
      p1Score++;
      document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Player 2 turn";
    }
    if (p1Score === winningscore) {
      p1Display.classList.add("winner");
      gameOver = true; //stop adding to score
    }
    p1Display.textContent = p1Score;
    if (gameOver) {
      p1Display.textContent = `Player 1 win ${p1Score}`;
      document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Game Over";
    }
  }
});

p2Button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (!gameOver) {
    if (turnTacker == 1) {
      p2Score++; //add 1 to p2 when clicked
      turnTacker = 0; // reset turn to 0. Player turn is over/off 
      document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Player 1 turn";
    }

    if (p2Score === winningscore) {
      p2Display.classList.add("winner");
      gameOver = true; //stop adding to score
    }
    p2Display.textContent = p2Score;

    if (gameOver) {
      p2Display.textContent = `Player 2 win ${p2Score}`;
      document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Game Over";
    }

  }
});

resetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  reset(); //function to start over
  p1Score = 0; //set player score back to 0
  p2Score = 0;
  //update score on html page to 0
  p1Display.textContent = 0;
  p2Display.textContent = 0;
  //remove winner class from both p1 &p2
  p1Display.classList.remove("winner");
  p2Display.classList.remove("winner");
  gameOver = false;
  document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "";
});

function reset() {
  p1Score = 0; //set player score back to 0
  p2Score = 0;
  //update score on html page to 0
  p1Display.textContent = 0;
  p2Display.textContent = 0;
  //remove winner class from both p1 &p2
  p1Display.classList.remove("winner");
  p2Display.classList.remove("winner");
  gameOver = false;
  turnTacker = 0;
}
numInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
  winningscoreDisplay.textContent = this.value;
  winningscore = Number(this.value);
  reset();
});
```

```css
.winner {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1> <span id="p1Display"> <span id="player1Win"></span> 0</span> to <span id="p2Display">0</span></h1>
<p>Play to: <span>5</span> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <span class="turn">Click button to play</span></p>
<input type="number" placeholder="Set number">
<button id="p1">Player 1</button>
<button id="p2">Player 2</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: You did not assign any listeners to the 2nd button.

Comment: because you set set whose turn it is back to zero each time....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your condition in player2 button listener. You have put a condition `if (turnTacker == 1) {` in the player2 button listener which is why it is not letting player2 start. See below javascript code to make this work.

```
let gameStart = false;
 p2Button.addEventListener("click", function() {
 if (!gameOver) {
  if(!gameStart) {
      gameStart = true;
      p2Score++; //add 1 to p2 when clicked
  turnTacker = 0; // reset turn to 0. Player turn is over/off 
  document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Player 1 turn";
  }
 if (turnTacker == 1) {
  p2Score++; //add 1 to p2 when clicked
  turnTacker = 0; // reset turn to 0. Player turn is over/off 
  document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Player 1 turn";
}

if (p2Score === winningscore) {
  p2Display.classList.add("winner");
  gameOver = true; //stop adding to score
}
p2Display.textContent = p2Score;

if (gameOver) {
  p2Display.textContent = `Player 2 win ${p2Score}`;
  document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Game Over";
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a variable called `gameStarted` and set it to false. Like this:

```
let p2Score = 0;
let p1Display = document.querySelector("#p1Display");
let p2Display = document.querySelector("#p2Display");
let gameOver = false; //keep track of state 
let winningscore = 5;
let turnTacker = 0; //keep track of p1Score and p1Score turn

let gameStarted = false;
```

Then in you click handlers you have:

Player 1:

```
p1Button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (!gameOver) {
    if (turnTacker == 0) {
      turnTacker = 1;
      p1Score++;
      document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Player 2 turn";
    }
    if (p1Score === winningscore) {
      p1Display.classList.add("winner");
      gameOver = true; //stop adding to score
    }
    p1Display.textContent = p1Score;
    if (!gameStarted) {
      gameStarted = true;
      turnTacker = 1;
      p1Score++;
      document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Player 2 turn";
    }
  }
  if (gameOver) { // Moved outside of if (!gameOver)
      p1Display.textContent = `Player 1 win ${p1Score}`;
      document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Game Over";
  }
});
```

And Player 2:

```
p2Button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (!gameOver) {
    if (turnTacker == 1) {
      p2Score++; //add 1 to p2 when clicked
      turnTacker = 0; // reset turn to 0. Player turn is over/off 
      document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Player 1 turn";
    }

    if (p2Score === winningscore) {
      p2Display.classList.add("winner");
      gameOver = true; //stop adding to score
    }
    p2Display.textContent = p2Score;

    if (!gameStarted) {
      gameStarted = true
      p2Score++; //add 1 to p2 when clicked
      turnTacker = 0; // reset turn to 0. Player turn is over/off 
      document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Player 1 turn";
    }

  }
  if (gameOver) { // moved out
      p2Display.textContent = `Player 2 win ${p2Score}`;
      document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Game Over";
  }
});
```

This will check if the game is not started or it is there turn.

Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

well, you do have this piece of code in:

```
let turnTacker = 0; //keep track of p1Score and p1Score turn
```

so change this to

```
let turnTacker = -1;
```

then add

```
p1Button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(turnTacker<0) turnTacker = 0;
  if (!gameOver) {
  ...
```

and

```
p2Button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(turnTacker<0) turnTacker = 1;
  if (!gameOver) {
  ...
```

and change in reset

```
function reset() {
...
turnTacker = -1;
```

This will keep the option to start available for any, player one or player two.

Answer (score 0):

You always put turnTacker=0 at start of the game as well as after reset button click. That's why always player1 button clicks work. if you want to randomly player1 button or player2 button work, then change in your code initialization of turnTracker variable value at the initial place and reset function. (it's kind of luck game)

```
turnTacker = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
```

It will give you random 0 or 1 .

```js
let p1Button = document.querySelector("#p1");
let p2Button = document.getElementById("p2");
let resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");
let numInput = document.querySelector("input");
let p = document.querySelector("p");
let winningscoreDisplay = document.querySelector("p span"); //slect p inside span
let p1Score = 0; //keep track of score
let p2Score = 0;
let p1Display = document.querySelector("#p1Display");
let p2Display = document.querySelector("#p2Display");
let gameOver = false; //keep track of state 
let winningscore = 5;
let turnTacker = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); //keep track of p1Score and p1Score turn

p1Button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (!gameOver) {
    if (turnTacker == 0) {
      turnTacker = 1;
      p1Score++;
      document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Player 2 turn";
    }
    if (p1Score === winningscore) {
      p1Display.classList.add("winner");
      gameOver = true; //stop adding to score
    }
    p1Display.textContent = p1Score;
    if (gameOver) {
      p1Display.textContent = `Player 1 win ${p1Score}`;
      document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Game Over";
    }
  }
});

p2Button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (!gameOver) {
    if (turnTacker == 1) {
      p2Score++; //add 1 to p2 when clicked
      turnTacker = 0; // reset turn to 0. Player turn is over/off 
      document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Player 1 turn";
    }

    if (p2Score === winningscore) {
      p2Display.classList.add("winner");
      gameOver = true; //stop adding to score
    }
    p2Display.textContent = p2Score;

    if (gameOver) {
      p2Display.textContent = `Player 2 win ${p2Score}`;
      document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "Game Over";
    }

  }
});

resetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  reset(); //function to start over
  p1Score = 0; //set player score back to 0
  p2Score = 0;
  //update score on html page to 0
  p1Display.textContent = 0;
  p2Display.textContent = 0;
  //remove winner class from both p1 &p2
  p1Display.classList.remove("winner");
  p2Display.classList.remove("winner");
  gameOver = false;
  document.querySelector(".turn").textContent = "";
});

function reset() {
  p1Score = 0; //set player score back to 0
  p2Score = 0;
  //update score on html page to 0
  p1Display.textContent = 0;
  p2Display.textContent = 0;
  //remove winner class from both p1 &p2
  p1Display.classList.remove("winner");
  p2Display.classList.remove("winner");
  gameOver = false;
  turnTacker = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
}
numInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
  winningscoreDisplay.textContent = this.value;
  winningscore = Number(this.value);
  reset();
});
```

```css
.winner {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1> <span id="p1Display"> <span id="player1Win"></span> 0</span> to <span id="p2Display">0</span></h1>
<p>Play to: <span>5</span> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <span class="turn">Click button to play</span></p>
<input type="number" placeholder="Set number">
<button id="p1">Player 1</button>
<button id="p2">Player 2</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```